# Multiple checkbox in php html

Tags: php, codeigniter, checkbox

I have a form in html like this, but it's error for checkbox question, someone please help me solve my problem.
It's multiple checkbox in multiple question

```
if(empty($tampil_pertanyaan)){
                echo "<tr><td colspan=\"6\">Data tidak tersedia</td></tr>";
    }else{
       $no = 1; //for question
       $no2 = 0; //for array
    foreach($tampil_pertanyaan as $row)
     {
    <input type="hidden" name="user[]" id="user[]" value="<?php echo $data["user"]; ?>">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="w3-check" name="ket_jawaban[<?php echo $no2;?>]"  id="ket_jawaban[<?php echo $no2;?>]" value="<?php echo $row->pil1;?>"  oninput="this.className = ''"></td>
        <td> <?php echo $row->pil1;?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="w3-check" name="ket_jawaban[<?php echo $no2;?>]"  id="ket_jawaban[<?php echo $no2;?>]" value="<?php echo $row->pil2;?>" oninput="this.className = ''"></td>
        <td> <?php echo $row->pil2;?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="w3-check" name="ket_jawaban[<?php echo $no2;?>]"  id="ket_jawaban[<?php echo $no2;?>]" value="<?php echo $row->pil3;?>" oninput="this.className = ''"></td>
        <td> <?php echo $row->pil3;?></td>
    </tr>
    $no++;
    $no2++;
}
```

And i my controller (i use Codeigniter)

```
public function insert_jawaban(){
        // Proses pemvalidasian data yg di input
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('ket_jawaban[]', 'ket_jawaban', 'trim|xss_clean');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
            echo validation_errors(); // tampilkan apabila ada error
        }else{

            //Insert ke tabel jawaban
            $result = array();
            foreach($_POST['ket_jawaban'] AS $key => $val){

                $result[] = array(
                    "id_jawaban"    => '',
                    "user"          => $_POST['user'][$key],
                    "ket_jawaban"   => $_POST['ket_jawaban'][$key]
                );
            }

            $res = $this->db->insert_batch('jawaban', $result);
}
```

why every time it returns one value, even though I checked three.

Firstly I apologize if there is any wrong in my question is because I am newbie here.
Thanks and please advise.

Comment: `"ket_jawaban[<?php echo $no2;?>]"` - Why give then all the same name if you want them to come back with different names? try ``"ket_jawaban[<?php echo $no2;?>][]"`` at least then you will get three values if all are checked. Debugging: `var_dump($_POST['ket_jawaban']);`

Comment: debugging return Null